# Can you add a mat tool tip to the header of a mat table column?

Tags: angular-material, tooltip, mat-table

I want to be able to add a tooltip that displays when hovering over the header of a column in a mat-table.
Is there a way to do this, because it does not display when I add the mat tooltip indicator.

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="marketDataSource" matSort multiTemplateDataRows class="w-100">
    <!-- Status Status -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header  matTooltip="Info about the action">
      Status
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <span>
        <mat-slide-toggle color="primary"></mat-slide-toggle>
      </span>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="marketDisplayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: marketDisplayedColumns;">
  </table>
```

Comment: what was not displaying? your code works fine. See it on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjsjcc?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: I forgot to import the tooltip module. import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';

Comment: No problem mate. I guess we should add an answer to it for search purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import `MatTooltip` module on your `component.ts`

```
 import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
```